# Joomla - page rendering control

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible to render another page instead of one currently being processed?

For instance, my plugin detects 404 error, sets corresponding HTTP headers, and then outputs a normal page from website - but under those HTTP 404 headers, so the browser and search engines will receive custom, good-looking 404 page.

Redirecting by

```
<? header("Location: ...'); ?>
```

is not an option. **I need stop rendering current page and render another, but display it under this, non-existing url.**

How this can be done?

Comment: Could you add a custom error.php file to your template? See the default error.php at templates/system/error.php.

Comment: Yes, it's an option, but I still need to render completely other page, with all modules etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a system event plugin, please see:

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System

in particular, the onAfterDispatch method:

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System#onAfterDispatch

The onAfterDispatch method is called after routing, and after Joomla has determined whether the url is valid, so it should be the time to get involved and redirect to another page.